# Derivative of Integrals w.r.t integral limits

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

When calculating the following derivative $\frac{d}{dx}\int^x _{ax} f(s)ds$, where $a<1$, is this equal to
$f(x)-f(ax)*\frac{dax}{dx}$?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the derivative = $f(x)-f(ax)a$.

Let $F(x):= \int_0^x f(s)ds$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$

$\int_{ax}^x f(s)ds=F(x)-F(ax)$

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!